# How to change an initial size of qtcreator's qtcreator_process_stub window (on Ubuntu)?

Tags: console, window, size, qt-creator

I have an application being developed in QT Creator on Ubuntu. I need to run some tests and to see their results I use console — qtcreator_process_stub window is opened. And now comes my question: how to set its initial size? (especially the width to make results more readable). Setting the width by mouse each time I run my app is quite annoying.

Comment: It might be sensible to submit the answer you found as an answer so that you can accept it a couple of days later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a simple solution:

Go to Tools->Options->General->Environment: System->Terminal. There is a command used to invoke a terminal. In my case I needed to change the command to:

```
xterm -geometry 250 -e
```

That's all;)

Comment: You can use this -geometry parameter for height as well, i.e. xterm -geometry 200x50 -e.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will be useful for **Windows** users:

You can right click on the console title bar (when running your program), select properties and change the font size (or other properties) in the font tab. It will be remembered for the future sessions.

For changing console size from command starts console use `cmd.exe "/k mode con: cols=150 lines=50"` (not working from Qt for me, changing `COMSPEC` do nothing).

Answer (score 0):

In more recent versions of Qt Creator (2.6.2 and up) this can be changed in

1. Projects
2. Run (from the top of the window)
3. In the run environment edit the COMSPEC field

Answer (score 0):

On Linux Mint you can do the following:

1. Open Terminal
2. Edit -> Profile Preferences -> General -> Use custom default terminal size

Set the Default size to a value which fit your needs.